# Geometric Transformation not working - degenerate points?

Tags: matrix, warning-messages, geometric-transform, coordinate-transformation

I've successfully used `FindGeometricTransformation` to project the simplex triangle onto the x-y plane:

```
{error, xf} = 
  FindGeometricTransform[
     {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, Tan[Pi/3], 0}/2}, 
     {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}];
```

When I try a simple extension of this to one higher dimension, it fails to compute the transformation.

```
{error, xf} = 
  FindGeometricTransform[
     {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, Tan[Pi/3], 0, 0}/2, {1/2, Tan[Pi/3]/4, Sqrt[2/3], 0}}, 
     {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}];
```

I get the error "FindGeometricTransform::insufficientPts: Need at least 2 non-degenerate pairs of points for Automatic transformation estimation." Any advice?

Comment: This error message is not documented anywhere in the help. So only suggestion is to contact support@wolfram.com, someone with access to the source code internally will be able to know. It could be simply that it does not support larger than 3 dimensions space.

Comment: You're right, @Nasser, after looking more carefully at the examples in [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunction.html), I think it is limited to 3D. It was easy enough to come up with a transformation matrix in my case.